# Chinese characters in bash variable are handled differently than in file

Tags: python, bash, unicode, cjk

I'm receiving Chinese characters in `curl` outputs and then feeding them as inputs to a Python script, but I get two very different behaviours depending on how I handle the characters.

The method which I prefer is giving me a UnicodeEncodeError.

**Preferred method:**

```sh
read -r C < <(curl ...)
python3 -c "import sys, urllib.parse; \
            urllib.parse.quote(sys.argv[1])" "$C"
# UnicodeEncodeError: 'utf-8' codec can't encode character '\udce5' in position 0: surrogates not allowed
```

**Alternate method:**

```sh
curl ... > tmp.txt
python3 -c "import urllib.parse; \
            with open('tmp.txt', encoding='utf-8') as f: \
                print(urllib.parse.quote(f.read()))"
# Outputs %E5%85%89%0A
```

Is there anything I can do to make the first method, which uses a bash variable, work? When I `echo $C` or `cat tmp.txt`, the Chinese character prints correctly to my terminal.

When I run `locale` on my machine, I get:

```sh
LANG=
LANGUAGE=
LC_CTYPE="POSIX"
LC_NUMERIC="POSIX"
LC_TIME="POSIX"
LC_COLLATE="POSIX"
LC_MONETARY="POSIX"
LC_MESSAGES="POSIX"
LC_PAPER="POSIX"
LC_NAME="POSIX"
LC_ADDRESS="POSIX"
LC_TELEPHONE="POSIX"
LC_MEASUREMENT="POSIX"
LC_IDENTIFICATION="POSIX"
LC_ALL=
```

**EDIT**
My environment is crouton (on ChromeOS). My bash is `GNU bash, version 4.3.48(1)-release (x86_64-pc-linux-gnu)`.

Comment: Why curl when you could request the URL from within Python?

Comment: @Tomalak, that may be the direction I should go, but most of the larger system is built in bash scripts, so I've been reluctant to redesign. Do you have any idea why I'm experiencing the problem posted, though?

Comment: that python error message is confused, and confusing. if I could figure out what it was supposed to mean I'd raise a bug report.

Comment: "surrogates not allowed" just means that encoding surrogate pairs in UTF-8 is invalid. The point of those pairs is their use in UTF-16, where one codepoint is represented as one or two 16-bit values. Searching for that error turns up a few hits, btw. That said, you need to extract a [mcve], because it's not really clear what exactly you have at which point. Also, what OS are you working on? That may well be important, because the passing of arguments and their encodings is OS-dependent (and complicated).

Comment: What about avoiding the undesired bash command line processing via `curl | python` and reading `sys.stdin` in Python?

Comment: @UlrichEckhardt, I'm in a crouton environment on ChromeOS. I've added an edit above with some details in case it's of interest to you.

Comment: @Tomalak, I was unable to move everything into Python because I'm making use of a nodejs library for another part of the system, and trying to open a subprocess for nodejs while supplying it with a Chinese character from Python results in the same `UnicodeEncodeError`.

Comment: Your code still doesn't allow reproducing the issue. Please read what MCVE means and pay attention to the little details.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### Set your locale

python uses the LC_CTYPE when interpreting argv. force a UTF8 locale.

```
read -r C < <(curl ...)
LC_CTYPE='en_US.UTF8' python3 -c "import sys, urllib.parse; \
            print(urllib.parse.quote(sys.argv[1]))" "$C"
```

Alternative to setting `LC_CTYPE`, you might just set `LANG`, depending on whether other parts of your system don't make use of `LC_CTYPE`.

or configure one as default.

### Install the locale (if necessary)

If the command `LC_CTYPE='en_US.UTF8'` results in an error, you might not have the `en_US.UTF8` locale (or whatever locale you choose) installed.

You can check to see what locales are installed by running `locale -a`. To install the 'en_US.UTF8' locale:

```
sudo locale-gen 'en_US'
sudo locale-gen 'en_US.UTF-8'
```

Comment: Thanks, @Jasen, but even entering `LC_CTYPE='en_US.UTF8'` results in error: `-su: warning: setlocale: LC_CTYPE: cannot change locale (en_US.UTF8)`

Comment: You might need to install that locale, maybe ask how to do that to Chrome-os in superuser.

Comment: Thanks. This gave me the insight to get a lot of the way there. Please excuse the edit.